# Callback from Tumblr removes my superview

Tags: ios, view, callback, tumblr

here's my problem. I set a callback URL in my app, but when it is called, it removes my superview.

More precisely, I set MyAppName in my info.plist as URL Scheme. ( I already use facebook API and it works well ).
Then, I call a view that is only partial, which means that it doesn't cover the entire screen. Just a part of it. After that, I click on the Tumblr button, which calls the webview enabling me to connect to my session. But when I come back to my app, the partial view has been removed from superview.

So I was wondering if I had to set something special in my callback URL, cause for now, it's just : MyAppName://Share (knowing that the "Share" is just for putting something. Either way, I just get redirected to the default URL, which is the Tumblr Home)

Thanks for help.

Comment: How/where do you create your partial view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I just discovered why it wasn't working : Since I'm using GTMOAuth, you push ViewController containing a webview, and assumes that you pushed it with a NavigationController, so I just pushed the GTMOAuth's ViewController to a NavigationController and it is being poped in the library's code.